# Run 64 bit Java with Internet explorer 11

Tags: java, windows, internet-explorer, 64-bit

I have Internet explorer 11. I have some help files which run only with 64 bit Java. By default IE was launching in 32 bit. After googling I found by enabling Enhanced protection, IE will launch in 64 bit. I was able to achieve IE in 64 bit. However it was still launching 32 bit Java.

Please note:- When there was a separate option of 64 bit with IE 9. I was able to run the help files with 64 bit version.

Please let me know how to run IE 11 with 64 bit Java in windows 7.

Answer (score 9):

I was searching for the same problem, here is the solution:

You only have to execute this script (save with .reg extension):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main]
"TabProcGrowth"=dword:00000000
```

Then you can stop and launch again IE x64 that will now work with Java x64. :)

Answer (score 0):

In 64 bit version, there is a separate link in the Start Menu to Internet Explorer for 64 bit. Also from TM you can figure it out if that application is using 32 bit or 64 bit

Comment: separate IE 64 bit was there till version 9. After that it has been removed. This is the reason for this question I am unable to run purely in 64 bit.