# 64 bit plugin of JRE/JDK/Java 9 is incompatible with IE 11 64 bit

Tags: java, applet, 64-bit, internet-explorer-11, java-9

I'm trying to run applet with JRE 9 on internet explorer 11 (64 bit), but it doesn't run. I've tried on windows 10 and server 2012.
In my application, we detect the installed jre version using deployJava.js. If no version is found a download prompt is displayed. This detection is done through javascript function getJREs which can be found [here](https://www.java.com/js/deployJava.txt). See snippet below:

```
getJREs: function() {
    var list = new Array();
    if (this.isPluginInstalled()) {
        var plugin =  this.getPlugin();
        var VMs = plugin.jvms;
        for (var i = 0; i < VMs.getLength(); i++) {
            list[i] = VMs.get(i).version;
        }
    } else {
        var browser = this.getBrowser();

        if (browser == 'MSIE') {
            if (this.testUsingActiveX('9')) {
                list[0] = '9';
            } else if (this.testUsingActiveX('1.8.0')) {
                list[0] = '1.8.0';
            } else if (this.testUsingActiveX('1.7.0')) {
                list[0] = '1.7.0';
            } else if (this.testUsingActiveX('1.6.0')) {
                list[0] = '1.6.0';
            } else if (this.testUsingActiveX('1.5.0')) {
                list[0] = '1.5.0';
            } else if (this.testUsingActiveX('1.4.2')) {
                list[0] = '1.4.2';
            } else if (this.testForMSVM()) {
                list[0] = '1.1';
            }
        } else if (browser == 'Netscape Family') {
            this.getJPIVersionUsingMimeType();
            if (this.firefoxJavaVersion != null) {
                list[0] = this.firefoxJavaVersion;
            } else if (this.testUsingMimeTypes('9')) {
                list[0] = '9';
            } else if (this.testUsingMimeTypes('1.8')) {
                list[0] = '1.8.0';
            } else if (this.testUsingMimeTypes('1.7')) {
                list[0] = '1.7.0';
            } else if (this.testUsingMimeTypes('1.6')) {
                list[0] = '1.6.0';
            } else if (this.testUsingMimeTypes('1.5')) {
                list[0] = '1.5.0';
            } else if (this.testUsingMimeTypes('1.4.2')) {
                list[0] = '1.4.2';
            } else if (this.browserName2 == 'Safari') {
                if (this.testUsingPluginsArray('9')) {
                    list[0] = '9';
                } else if (this.testUsingPluginsArray('1.8')) {
                    list[0] = '1.8.0';
                } else if (this.testUsingPluginsArray('1.7')) {
                    list[0] = '1.7.0';
                } else if (this.testUsingPluginsArray('1.6')) {
                    list[0] = '1.6.0';
                } else if (this.testUsingPluginsArray('1.5')) {
                    list[0] = '1.5.0';
                } else if (this.testUsingPluginsArray('1.4.2')) {
                    list[0] = '1.4.2';
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (this.debug) {
        for (var i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) {
            log('[getJREs()] We claim to have detected Java SE ' + list[i]);
        }
    }

    return list;
}
```

In the case of JRE 9 this function is not able to detect the java version and applet failed to load.
Here are the discussionsI saw which talks in same lines:

1. [JDK-8188306](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8188306)
2. [JDK-8193431](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8193431)
3. [JDK-8162522](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8162522)
4. [This microsoft answer](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie11-iewindows_10/cannot-access-secure-website-that-requires-java/173f732b-7377-41f6-8c6f-2ae171f4da7a?auth=1)
5. [This SO OP solves it using 32 bit JRE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45423357/ie-11-cant-find-java-plugin-to-run-applet). In my case its not possible as Oracle didn't release the 32 bit version of JRE/JDK 9.

Also I could see that both the Java SSV plugin helpers are listed as incompatible in the list of IE addons.

I've tried to load the applet with JRE 1.8 (both 32 bit and 64 bit), it loads perfectly fine.

I understand that applets have been deprecated in java 9, but deprecation doesn't mean they won't run, do they?

PS: I would appreciate if you don't ask me not to use applet as I have to do it for legacy purposes. So, thanks in advance!

Comment: *"I understand that applets have been deprecated in java 9, but deprecation doesn't mean they won't run, do they?"* See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/moving-to-a-plugin-free-web). BTW - whether Oracle deprecates them or not is irrelevant, if browser manufacturers are no longer supporting applets (which is the case).

Comment: @AndrewThompson I agree too. But I can't see any official source(either oracle or microsoft) which says IE 11 can't load applets with JRE/JDK 9.

Comment: *"But I can't see any official source.."* And I can't see any point in spending time trying to solve this. I'm not an 'official source' but I am the [top ranked provider of applet answers](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/applet/topusers) and the only person to bother commenting so far. Good luck with it.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I absolutely understand what you're trying to say and deeply appreciate your responses. Thanks.

Comment: To force IE11 to use 64bit plugin, I needed to check "Enable 64-bit processes for Enhanced Protected Mode" in IE11 setting, and set "Windows Components/Internet Explorer/Tab Process Growth" to 0 in group policy.

Comment: Are you stuck with applets? I recently had a project to migrate to web start: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/deploy/migrating-java-applets-jnlp.htm in the long term this could be a solution, but if it is a business requirement to stick to applets you can have multiple java versions I guess...

Comment: How about Java10? "Java SE 9 will be a short term release, and users should immediately transition to the next release (18.3) when available." I think Java9 as JRE is quite marginal.

Comment: Did you also try to use the <applet> tag with a jnlp_href attribute, a detached jnlp file and just not use the deployjava scripts?

Comment: @user188737 I haven't tried that. Would my plugins be compatible in that case?

Comment: I have validated that IE11 in 64-bit mode does work with JRE 10 in 64-bit if you make the settings Zakki mentioned. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/32306460/2824577. In JRE 10 you get a big deprecation warning on startup of the applet.

Comment: Unfortunately the end of 32-bit JRE makes it impossible to run applets in IE11 without making non-default settings to it. Applets can still run but only if the end-user or admin makes the necessary settings to make IE work with 64-bit JRE. The install of the JRE doesn't make these settings, and they break 32-bit only plugins. So this will only work in a controlled environment.

Answer (score 1):

The end of 32-bit JRE by Oracle makes it impossible to run applets in IE11 without making non-default settings to it for clients installing the Oracle JRE. Applets can still run but only if the end-user or admin makes the necessary settings to make IE work with 64-bit JRE. The install of the JRE doesn't make these settings, they break 32-bit only plugins and revert IE11 to a one process model. So this will only work in a controlled environment.

See this question for settings:
[Run 64 bit Java with Internet explorer 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21499524/run-64-bit-java-with-internet-explorer-11/32306460#32306460)

Theoretically java web start should work even without forcing 64-bit settings for IE and then you could run an applet that doesn't require javascript bindings in the webstart appletviewer. So, in very specific circumstances that might be an option to run an applet, starting from default IE11 with JRE10.

See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/applet_migration.html

A little excursion for the curious, there is actually a 32-bit Windows build of openjdk 10 here: https://github.com/ojdkbuild/ojdkbuild.
It does include the Ice Tea Web (ITW) launcher, but this uses npapi, so doesn't work anymore today for in-browser applets.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the link below.

Certifications with EBS 11i still pending

We plan to certify IE 11 with EBS 11i.  This certification us underway now and will be released soon.

If you're running EBS 11i, you must ensure that your mission-critical desktops remain on an earlier certified browsers until this certification is completed.  As of the time this article was published, certified browsers include IE 10 and Firefox ESR 31 for Windows desktops.

You can block automatic updates by using Microsoft's Internet Explorer 11 Blocker Toolkit:

https://blogs.oracle.com/stevenchan/internet-explorer-11-certified-with-e-business-suite-122-and-120